# How to update stock quantity in the database?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have windows application to add the purchase information. Before purchase is added to the database, user selects the items from the combo box and adds to the listbox. When user click add purchase, there will be either one or more than one item in the database.

The name of there items exactly match the product name in the database.

I would like to get string of each item in the listbox, and then write sql query which reduces the quantity of items in the database. The total quantity is stored in table Product under Quantity column.

Is there anyone with idea to perform this task?

I am trying to pass the string of the listbox item to this method one by one

```
 public string Update(string product)
        {
            // Create connection object
            int ix = 0;
            string rTurn = "";
            OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                oleConn.Open();
                string sql = "UPDATE [Product] SET [Quantity]=[Quantity] - 1 " + " WHERE [Product Name]= " + product;
                OleDbCommand oleComm = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);

                oleComm.Parameters.Add("@product", OleDbType.Char).Value = product;

                ix = oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (ix > 0)
                    rTurn = "Stock Updated";
                else
                    rTurn = "Update Failed";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                oleConn.Close();
            }
            return rTurn;
        }
```

And above method will get product name from method below:

```
 public string updateStock()
        {
            string listItem = string.Empty;
            foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
            {



                if (listBox1.Items.IndexOf(listBoxItem) < listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
                {
                    listItem = listBox1.Items.ToString();
                }
            }

            return listItem;

        }
```

And I will call this code from the button event handler

```
Update(updateStock());
```

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the table, maybe with a [SQL Fiddle](http//sqlfiddle.com) example?

Comment: are you asking for help on the SQL query, on how to get the names out of the listbox, or all the stuff in between? This question is massively broad I'm afraid.... maybe you need to divide it up into separate questions, and show what you've tried for each one.

Comment: I just like to get string of each item in listbox and pass that string to the update method.. Let me edit the question..

Comment: I m updating the answer

Comment: @peterm question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public void UpdateStock()
{
    foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
    {
        string result = Update(listBoxItem.ToString());
    }
}

public string Update(string product)
{
    // Create connection object
    string rTurn = "";
    OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    try
    {
        oleConn.Open();
        string sql = "UPDATE [Product] SET [Quantity]=[Quantity] - 1 WHERE [Product Name] = @product";
        OleDbCommand oleComm = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);

        oleComm.Parameters.Add("@product", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = product;

        oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        rTurn = "Stock Updated";    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        rTurn = "Update Failed";
    }
    finally
    {
        oleConn.Close();
    }
    return rTurn;
}
```

**EDIT**: You can easily specify the size when adding the parameter - as demonstrated above. 50 is just arbitrary. You should ensure that the size is the same as that of the target [Product Name] column.

Comment: it works for the item with one word like "Laptop" but if you have item like "Samsung Galaxy S3", it throws error.